# Return rows of found and not found

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to return all rows based in condition? Example:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 TABLE
WHERE
 USER IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

In the example above it will return only if there is a user A, B and C. If The user C doesn't exist it will return only 2 rows, A and B. I would like to have 3 rows, and the C with empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a cte to return A, B, and C rows. Outer join with that cte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```
SELECT
    t1.[user],
    t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 'A' [user]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C'
) t1    
LEFT JOIN 
    table_name t
ON t.[user] = t1.[user];
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of LEFT join here..

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT 'a' AS user UNION ALL
 SELECT 'b' 
  SELECT 'c'
 )
SELECT * FROM cte
LEFT JOIN tablename ON yourcolumnName = user
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.